# What are the processes and requirements for obtaining a restraining order against an abusive family member in Florida?

Tags: florida, restraining-orders, abuse

I want to obtain a protective bubble of distance around myself that could be enforced in case this person who has done many terrible things to me comes within any certain vicinity. Does this require them to be served notice? What if they are out of the country but soon returning? Can an order be obtained in their absence? How does this basically work?

Thanks

Comment: What terrible things has that relative done?

Comment: Go down to the court and talk to the clerk. They will help you find the paperwork to file a PPO, then a hearing will be set. The judge may issue an interim PPO until the person can be properly served.